# Android Studio Error(com/intellij/codeInsight/daemon/impl/analySis/RefCountHolder)

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

Every time when, I start android studio it gives me error. I am new user to android studio please help me to understand this error..

**ERROR**

com/intellij/codeInsight/daemon/impl/analySis/RefCountHolder

Comment: Try to update your android studio or install a latest fresh copy.

Comment: Hey Dexto, thanks after installing fresh copy of Android Studio Its working fine.

Comment: Thanks! for conforming. I have posted the solution as answer kindly accept to help other user in community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to update your android studio or install a latest fresh copy